# Where to cleanup cloudinary file uploads after rspec/cucumber run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, cloudinary

I use `fixture_file_upload` in my `FactoryGirl` methods to test file uploads. Problem is that after cleaning the database, all these uploaded files remain on `Cloudinary`.

I've been using `Cloudinary::Api.delete_resources` using a rake task to get rid of them, but I'd rather immediately clean them up before `DatabaseCleaner` removes all related public id's.

Where should I interfere with `DatabaseCleaner` as to remove these files from `Cloudinary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @phoet's input, and given the fact that cloudinary limits the amount of API calls you can do on a single day, as well as the amount of images you can cleanup in a single call, I created a class

```
class CleanupCloudinary
  @@public_ids = []

  def self.add_public_ids
    Attachinary::File.all.each do |image|
      @@public_ids << image.public_id

      clean if @@public_ids.count == 100
    end
  end

  def self.clean
    Cloudinary::Api.delete_resources(@@public_ids) if @@public_ids.count > 0

    @@public_ids = []
  end
end
```

which I use as follows: in my factory girl file, I make a call to immediately add any public_ids after creating an advertisement:

```
after(:build, :create) do 
  CleanupCloudinary.add_public_ids
end
```

in env.rb, I added

```
at_exit do
  CleanupCloudinary.clean
end
```

as well as in spec_helper.rb

```
config.after(:suite) do
  CleanupCloudinary.clean
end
```

This results in, during testing, cleanup after each 100 cloudinary images, and after testing, to clean up the remainder

Comment: The `:build`option is useless in `after(:build, :create) do` because it – evidently – doesn't write in the database. Otherwise to make it work in Minitest, replace the `at_exit` and `config.after` by adding `teardown { CleanupCloudinary.clean }` in `test_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

i would have two ways of doing things here.

firstly, i would not upload anything to cloudinary unless it is a integration test. i would use a mock, stub or test-double.

secondly, if you really really really need to upload the files for whatever reason, i would write a hook that does automatic cleanup in an `after_all` hook of you tests.

Comment: I'm using the attachinary gem, in combination with cloudinary, and haven't found a way yet to stub around the "has_attachment" directive in my model. Does a "after_all" exist that runs after all tests have run?

Comment: just do it for every test-file, should not make any difference.

Comment: it depends: `config.after(:each) { your_hook }` is 100% dry. you could also use tags to mark spec where this has to run. there are endless ways to do this with rspec.

Answer (score 0):

To make @Danny solution work in Minitest, instead of `at_exit` and `config.after`, add in `test_helper.rb`:

```rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ...
  Minitest.after_run do
    puts 'Cloudinary cleanup'
    CleanupCloudinary.clean
  end
end
```

If you need to cleanup more often, you can use `teardown { CleanupCloudinary.clean }` either globally in `test_helper.rb` or in specific test files.

And of course in the factory you still need:

```rb
after(:create) do 
  CleanupCloudinary.add_public_ids
end
```