# delete all images in a cloudinary account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

How can I delete all images in a cloudinary account via the **ruby API**?

Is there a special flag for deleting all resources via the `delete_resource_by_tag` method?

eg

```
Cloudinary::Api::delete_resources_by_tag "all"
```

Comment: i never used it, but i saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208892/where-to-cleanup-cloudinary-file-uploads-after-rspec-cucumber-run

Comment: the api itself does not seem to have a "delete_all" method: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They seem to have added the ability to delete all to the gem since this question was posted:

```
Cloudinary::Api.delete_all_resources
```

I found it to not delete *all* but to delete perhaps 1k images, since it took 5 calls for me to delete 4500 or so images.

Comment: how can i do the same using NODEJS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the admin API for browsing through images and performing bulk deletions. For more details see the following blog post and the documentation: 
http://cloudinary.com/blog/restful_api_for_managing_your_website_s_images_and_other_online_assets

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources

If you need some help in deleting a large number of images, you can go to the '**Settings**' page from the management console, and click on the "**Bulk delete images**" link on the right to send Cloudinary some details about the images you wish to delete: the account's cloud name and the estimated number of images. And you'll be updated when the deletion is done.